# Доступ только с ipv4

Tags: apache

На сайте происходит сохранения ip в базу данных, при этом сохранятся туда должны только ipv4. Как результат мне нужно делать дополнительные проверки.Чтобы избежать этого в apache2 в httpd.conf можно написать

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80Listen 0.0.0.0:443
```

Мне же это не подходит по 2 причинам:

- сайт может быть установлен на хостинге, где нет доступа к httpd.conf
- сайт должен уметь работать с ipv6, но часть сайта не должна.

Как понять вторую причину? Файлы php предоставляют собой api, который может быть уставлен на сайт. Например, это веб-прокси (как бы глупо не звучало)Сам api может быть установлен в корневую папку сайта (тогда сайт предоставляет собой только api) или же в папку. То есть доступ к api может быть таким:

```
http://example.org/api.phphttp://example.org/path/api.phphttp://example.org/path/ .... /api.php
```

**Как я могу прописать доступ к api только с ipv4 в htaccess?** Может можно регулярными выражениями как-то?

Использую Apache 2.4 и Windows 8. Программное обеспечения может меняться.

Answer (score 1):

А всё оказывается очень просто! Адреса v6 нужно в конфиге прописывать в квадратных скобках, как вот тут, в доке написано: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.htmlНу и ниже доку прочитать насчёт v6 тоже не мешает.

Comment: @Anton  Reshin Если сайт использует ipv4, то к нему могут получить доступ пользователи с ipv6? мне нужно запретить доступ ipv6 к указанной папке сайта с помощью .htaccess

Comment: А это вообще не в .htaccess делается, а в конфиге Апача!Потому, что в .htaccess нет распознавания v4 и v6 протоколов.

Comment: @Anton  Reshin к этому я и веду. Нарыл вот что https://plus.google.com/+AlexandreAlapetite/posts/j9zohK8AgWg но мне нужно наоборот: отбросить ipv6 и разрешить ipv4. Может как-то через диапазон? регулярным выражениями? Я слабо в этом понимаю.

Comment: Ага! Я, похоже, понял что вам нужно! Вам нужно адреса V4 пропускать перед адресами V6! Ну и настройте это через allow и deny! Они же по разным протоколам.Поясняю: одно другому не мешает.

Comment: @Anton  Reshin `Order Deny,AllowDeny from allAllow from 0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255`С диапазоном походу проблемы.